# How do I solve for x when given the derivative equation and the slope of the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The derivative of a function $f$ is given by $f′(x)=0.1x+e^{0.25x}$. At what value of $x$ for $x>0$ does the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x$ have slope $2$ ?

This provides the derivative and slope of the tangent line but I am not sure how to solve for x

Comment: You have to do this numerically, unless you want to mess with the Lambert W function.

Comment: This is not doable by hand. This implicit equation can be solved numerically at a calculator or computer.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the exact value is hard and even if you have a "closed form expression" it'll probably not be "just some number" (see for example the result here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2+%3D+0.1x%2Be%5E%280.25x%29), so we'll have to resort to numerics. If this sounds daunting note that you can get a super simple and good approximation of the actual solution in this case:

first note that as $x$ grows, you can basically ignore the linear part of $f'$ as it'll become neglible in contrast to the exponential one. So lets assume that $x$ is sufficiently large and solve $2=e^{x/4} \iff x = 4 \ln 2$. Since $f'$ is monotonous we expect our actual answer in the domain $(0, 4 \ln2)$. Taylorexpand $f'$ around $4 \ln 2 = \ln 16$ to get $f'(x) \approx 2.27726+0.6(x-\ln 16) + 0.0625 (x - \ln 16)^2$ (note also that the coeffiecients in the expansion become quite small as we go to higher degrees). We now set this equal to $2$ and solve again to find $x \approx 2.2858$ or $x \approx -6.3406$. We're clearly after the $x \approx 2.2858$ solution. If you want more precision you can repeat this process:

- taylorexpand around the $x$ value we just found
- solve the resulting polynomial equation

but the first estimate is already quite a good estimate, if we consider that the actual value (numerically computed) is at around $x \approx 2.28688$. So via a simple approximation we've managed to find an approximate solution with a relative error of $\sim 0.047\%$.